# Can global parameters be used with dynamic_reconfigure?

Tags: ros, parameters, param-server, dynamic-reconfigure

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,
when using dynamic_reconfigure, the parameters used are linked to specific nodes. For example, if there is a **cfg/MyConfig.cfg** file with a parameter such as **gen.add('my_param', int_t,....)**, and this runs in node **my_node**, then the parameter server will have a parameter such as **/my_node/my_param**. Is it possible to have instead a global parameter **/my_param**?

Moreover, would it be possible to use that single cfg file for two (or more) nodes? That is, upon modifications of **/my_param**, a node, eg. **my_node_1** should call certain callback **cbk_1**, and **my_node_2** should call certain callback **cbk_2**.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/268386/can-global-parameters-be-used-with-dynamic_reconfigure?/) by [dieg0-](https://answers.ros.org/users/29205/dieg0-/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2017-08-09

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I made a script https://github.com/lucasw/dynamic_reconfigure_tools/blob/master/dynamic_reconfigure_tools/scripts/dr2dr.py that creates a dynamic reconfigure server out of specified elements of other dr servers.

In this example https://github.com/lucasw/vimjay/blob/master/config/stop_motion_dr.yaml there is a a control 'capture_single' and another control 'WhiteBalanceTemperature' on two different dr servers, but running dr2dr creates a new control panel with those two (and many other controls on those two servers excluded):

```
# [server name, server value name, type, level, description, default value, min, max]
capture_single: ["/usb_cam/image_deque", "capture_single", "bool", 1, "capture single image", False, False, True]
white_balance_temperature: ["/usb_cam/v4l2ucp_ddr", "WhiteBalanceTemperature", "int", 2, "Change camera white balance", 5000, 2800, 6500]
```

(I haven't tested dr2dr recently so possibly it needs some cleanup)

It wouldn't be too hard to make it support 1-to-many controls rather than just 1-to-1: you would be able to change parameters in many other dr servers from one master parameter, and changing any of those individual parameters could also get reflected across the rest.

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2017-08-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0